# How to move a view while scrolling a UITableView?

Tags: uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a searchBox and a table view which shows results. What I want is, when I scroll up in the table view, searchBox goes up with the same speed and distance.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if(tableView.contentOffset.y >= 110){
        CGRect frame = searchBox.frame;
        frame.origin.y = - (tableView.contentOffset.y-110);
        searchBox.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

This code is ok if I scroll slowly.

If I scroll very fast, some part of the searchBox is not displayed when I scroll down.

Where am I wrong?